# Wordpress query returning posts with very old date when querying for future events

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I'm doing a wordpress query for future events based on the date code stored in a meta value. I'm getting the future events as expected but some very old events from the 1990s are being returned in the query after the future events. Is there any way around this?

```
$today = time();

$futureloop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'exhibitions',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => '100',
'meta_query' => array(
 array(
  'key' => 'exhibition_date',
  'compare' => '>=',
  'value' => $today,
 )
),
'meta_key' => 'exhibition_date',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
) );
while ( $futureloop->have_posts() ) : $futureloop->the_post();
```

For example I have one event that occurred in April 1990 that is showing up.
When I echo $today and the date of the event this is the result:

639273600 $exhibiton_date

1559283337 $today

Comment: what date format is exhibition_date?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `type` parameter in the `meta_query` to **date** or **datetime**?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `exhibition_date` is `DATETIME` type. So you should try `meta_query` as below.

```
$today= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

'meta_query' => array(
 array(
  'key' => 'exhibition_date',
  'value' => $today,
  'compare' => '<=',  
  'type'      => 'DATETIME',
 )
),
```

Hope it will work for you.

[Class Reference/WP Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)